# Apply Quicksort Algorithm to [23,12,11,0,5,2,7,8,15,14]

Tags: algorithms

I have an array, [23,12,11,0,5,2,7,8,15,14]. I choose the rightmost element (14) as the pivot and set lo = 23 and hi = 15. Then since lo = 23 > pivot = 14, I don't change the position of lo. However for hi = 15 it is > pivot = 14, so I move one step to the left, which results in hi = 8. Since hi = 8 is < pivot = 14, I fix the position of hi = 8. Then I swap lo = 23 and hi = 8 which gives the new array [8,12,11,0,5,2,7,23,15,14].

The next lo position is 12 and hi position is 7. Since hi = 7 is < pivot = 14, I fix the hi position at 7. However, for the lo position at 12, it is smaller than the pivot = 14. So, I increase the lo position to 11 then 0 then 5 then 2, all of which is still < pivot = 14. I increase the lo position to 7 which is the hi position too.

After this step, I'm unsure on how to continue. I know that if the element at the position of lo=hi is > pivot, then we can swap it, and obtain 2 partitions (left of pivot and right of pivot). However, in the case the element at lo=hi is < pivot = 14, I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: Do all that's necessary to `obtain 2 partitions [(no larger than than pivot, no smaller than pivot)]` and continue just as in the case `> pivot`.

Comment: Program quicksort and trace its execution on your example.